# `transferSize' in window.performance returns 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a electron application to show performance statistics. One such a column which displays, "Size" of the resource available in `window.performance.getEntries()`.

Wondering the `transferSize` always returns 0 in the JSON.

I assume, is this because of the cache? if yes, How I make sure , that ensures I always get `transferSize`.

Comment: _"The [`transferSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize) read-only property represents the size (in octets) of the fetched resource. The size includes the response header fields plus the response payload body (as defined by [RFC7230](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7230.html#message.body)). **If the resource is fetched from a local cache, or if it is a cross-origin resource, this property returns zero**."_